# Best way to Start a expense/budget tool in PowerApps

Tags: powerapp

I'm envisioning having an agreed upon budget that I store on the cloud and having folks submit 'invoices' based off that budget.

Question 1) I want to have the invoicer be able to select from multiple types of expense, draw from multiple piles of funds, and have input validation assure them that they are inputting correctly. Which back-end data service is best? OneDrive via an Excel file? Some kind of Sharepoint resource I should look into?

Question 2) I completed the PowerApps tutorial and they had me copy-pasting code. What language of code is this? Is it possible to do everything without code?

Question 3) Where's the best place to ask PowerApps questions besides this subreddit? Stackexchange?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerApps is a good approach to start this. Consider based on on-going budget and almost write less code or no code solution

1. SharePoint - Because you can use the same license with PowerApps plan(other are definitely good but it will gonna cost little bit extra. There is no straightforward metadata extraction you need to open the files manually to correct the code to do this process. But if you use SharePoint list then can directly go there and edit item as appropriate). Also, If you choose SharePoint it comes with OOTB Workflow and CMS capabilities.
2. PowerApps is no-code or rather less-code(depend upon needs in your use case) platform but gives us the rich capability to design screen. However to apply business logic we need to use easy excel like *[forumlas](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/tutorials/working-with-formulas/)* with an [*in-built function*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/formula-reference) for easy to complex tasks.

> It also provides rich set of [*connectors*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/connections-list) from [*MSFlow*](https://flow.microsoft.com/) to [*Azure Functions*](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/).

- PowerApps community is becoming huge day by day. one can connect to this official *[Microsoft PowerApps Community forum](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/PowerApps-Community/ct-p/PowerApps1)*.

**Related Articles:**

- Create an app from scratch - [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/get-started-create-from-blank), [here](http://ratsubsharewall.blogspot.com/2017/03/develop-powerapps-from-scratch-series1.html)
- Custom connectors - [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/index)
- Building flows - [here](https://flow.microsoft.com/documentation/multi-step-logic-flow/)

Comment: thanks @little_big_thoughts (apparently the @ mentions don't work on Stack Exchange)

Anyway, this is great, I'll get started. Any go-to resources for how to correctly do SharePoint Lists? For example, when I was dabbling in MS Access a few years ago, I learned about normalization and naming conventions.

Comment: Glad that it helps you! Refer Detailed Microsoft recommendation/steps/Known issues to use SharePoint as a Datasource for PowerApps. 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/connections/connection-sharepoint-online